# how to limit nested arrays field returned in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, meteor, underscore.js

here's the courses collection :

```
{
  "_id": "RtPA6Cxs3fzJcGpgP",
  "Seasons": [
    {
      "title": "intro",
      "Episodes": [
        {
          "title": "what is c++?",
          "length": "12:52",
          "free_url": "free-episode-1.mp4"
        },
        {
          "title": "why c++?",
          "length": "05:20",
          "paid_url": "premium-episode-1.mp4"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "first season",
      "Episodes": [
        {
          "title": "declare variables",
          "length": "12:35",
          "paid_url": "premium-episode-2.mp4"
        },
        {
          "title": "pointers",
          "length": "04:00",
          "free_url": "free-episode-2.mp4"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to get (everything except **paid_url**s):

```
{
  "_id": "RtPA6Cxs3fzJcGpgP",
  "Seasons": [
    {
      "title": "intro",
      "Episodes": [
        {
          "title": "what is c++?",
          "length": "12:52",
          "free_url": "free-episode-1.mp4"
        },
        {
          "title": "why c++?",
          "length": "05:20"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "first season",
      "Episodes": [
        {
          "title": "declare variables",
          "length": "12:35"
        },
        {
          "title": "pointers",
          "length": "04:00",
          "free_url": "free-episode-2.mp4"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

tried these queries :
1. this works on client side (chrome console) but it doesn't work on "meteor mongo":

```
db.courses.find({_id: "RtPA6Cxs3fzJcGpgP"}, {fields: {"Seasons.Episodes.paid_url": 0}}).fetch()
```

the error I get on "meteor mongo" :

> "$err" : "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue Unsupported projection option: fields: { Seasons.$.Episodes.$.paid_url: 0.0 }"`

2. tried this too :

   ```
   Courses.find({_id: this.params.id}, {fields: {"Seasons.$.Episodes.$.paid_url": 0}});
   ```

Comment: you can't use `.$.` you need to specify the exact number you're looking for it's not supported on minimongo

Comment: the query works without $ signs in chrome console but it doesn't work in Meteor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct query:

```
db.courses.find({_id: "RtPA6Cxs3fzJcGpgP"}, {"Seasons.Episodes.paid_url": 0}})
```

No need of fields

Comment: still doesn't work in meteor. the result is like `db.courses.find({_id: "RtPA6Cxs3fzJcGpgP"})`

Comment: @Matthias Eckhart I tried my first query without fetch() and it's working! I'm using Meteor 1.2. `db.courses.find({_id: "RtPA6Cxs3fzJcGpgP"}, {fields: {"Seasons.Episodes.paid_url": 0}})`